# suppose $A$ is a set where $x \in A \iff x + T \in A$ and $\mu$ denotes the lesbesque measure. prove that $\mu(A\cap[0,T]) = \mu(A\cap[a,a+T]) $

Tags: measure-theory

suppose $A$ is a measurable set where $x \in A \iff x + T \in A$ and $\mu$ denotes the lesbesque measure. prove that $\mu(A\cap[0,T]) = \mu(A\cap[a,a+T])$

i know that the lesbesque measure is translation-invariant: $\mu(B) = \mu(x+B)$.

i tried doing the following:

$\mu(A\cap[a,a+T]) = \mu(A) + \mu([a,a+T]) - \mu(A\cup[a,a+T]) = \mu(A) + \mu([0,T]) - \mu(A\cup[a,a+T]$.

So we can also prove $\mu(A\cup[a,a+T] = \mu(A\cup[0,T])$. the main problem here is that i can't specifically can use the translation-invariation of $\mu$ unless $A$ and $[a,a+T]$ are disjoint.

I tried using the fact that $A = A + T$ as wel, which gives us: $\mu(A \cup \{a\}) = \mu(A \cup \{0\})$. But i don't know for sure if this step is valid.

Any hints for this problem?

Kees

Comment: Why should the set $A$ be measurable?

Comment: yeah it should sorry

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Compare $\mu(A\cap [0,a))$ and $\mu(A\cap(T,a+T])$.

Comment: Because $A = A + T = A + 2T \dots $. we see:

$\mu(A \cap [T, a+T]) = \mu (A+T \cap,[T,a+T]) = \mu(A \cap [0,a])$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\mu(A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_A \, \mathrm{d}\mu$ where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$. Due to the Assumptions this is $T$-periodic (or constant or $\frac{T}{k}$-periodic for some natural $k$).
Furthermore $\chi_{A\cap B} = \chi_A \cdot \chi_B$. Now use the substitution rule and you are done.